# Pandas Combining two rows into one

Tags: python, pandas

I've created a Pandas program that imports csv
This is my first column

this is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/K5bjjNQu')
```

and I already tried this to locate it:

```
groepen1 = df.loc[:, ['voer groepsnaam in']]
groepen2 = df.loc[:, ['groepsnaam']]
groepen_totaal = groepen1.join(groepen2)
```

The first row

```
voer groepsnaam in
0                 NaN
1                 NaN
2                 NaN
3                 NaN
4             maarten
5                 NaN
6                 NaN
7             maarten
8                 NaN
9                 NaN
10                NaN
11                NaN
12                NaN
13                NaN
14                NaN
15                NaN
16             mirjam
17                NaN
18                NaN
19             Mirjam
20                NaN
21                NaN
22                NaN
```

My second row:

```
groepsnaam
        0          NaN
        1          NaN
        2          NaN
        3      maarten
        4          NaN
        5          NaN
        6       Mirjam
        7          NaN
        8          NaN
        9          NaN
        10         NaN
        11         NaN
        12         NaN
        13   De Jagers
        14   De Jagers
        15   De Jagers
        16         NaN
        17  De Henkies
        18         NaN
        19         NaN
        20         NaN
        21         NaN
        22         NaN
```

I'm trying to combine the two in a different column and turn it intro this:

```
group3
1
2
3 maarten
4 maarten
5
6 Mirjam
7 maarten
8
9
10
11
12
13 De jagers
14 De jagers
15 De jagers
16 Mirjam
17 De henkies
18
19 Mirjam
20
21
22
```

Can you guys help me to try to combine this?
I already tried to use .join but it didn't work.

Comment: What gets priority when values overlap? You probably want `.update` or `.combine_first`

Comment: When I try to update .update it gives no results, when I try to use .combine_first it shows it side by side

Comment: Because the columns have different names. Rename them both to `'group3'` and it will work.